# Cannot Find Service - GHZ to load test GRPC Service

Tags: grpc, load-testing

I'm trying to test a GRPC Service using GHZ. However, I get the error -
Cannot find service "com.server.grpc.Executor"

Config.json file:

```
    "proto": "/Users/dev/Desktop/ghz/execute.proto",
    "call": "com.server.grpc.Executor.execute",
    "total": 2000,
    "concurrency": 50,
    "data": {
        "param1": "test-data1",
        "param2": "test-data2",

    },
    "max-duration": "10s",
    "host": "<ip-address>:9090",
    "c": 10,
    "n": 200
}
```

proto file:

```
option java_package= "com.server.grpc";
option java_multiple_files = true;



service Executor  {
    rpc execute(ExecuteRequest) returns (ExecuteResponse);
}


message ExecuteRequest {
  string param1 = 1;
  string param2= 2;
}

message ExecuteResponse {
    bool res = 1;
    string msg = 2;
}
```

Running using command: ghz --config=<path/to/config>/config.json

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your protobuf file should contain e.g.:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package example;
...
```

Then, your service would be fully-qualified by `example.Executor.execute` not `com.server.grpc.Execute.execute` which is a language-specific (I assume, Java by your `option`) fully-qualified name.

I assume you unintentionally omitted the opening brace (`{`) of the JSON file but that, of course, is required.

JSON is *challenging* your `"param2": "test-data2"` must not be terminated with `,` because it's the last item in the list; so drop that comma.

```
{
    "proto": "/Users/dev/Desktop/ghz/execute.proto",
    "call": "example.Executor.execute",
    "total": 2000,
    "concurrency": 50,
    "data": {
        "param1": "test-data1",
        "param2": "test-data2"
    },
    "max-duration": "10s",
    "host": "<ip-address>:9090",
    "c": 10,
    "n": 200
}
```

Assuming your service is running on `<ip-address>:9090`, that should then work!